# Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-data

Всем привет.
Первый проект. Spring + DataJPA, MVC, Tomcat

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]

Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webapp-context.xml]

Запускаю **app.java**

```
    public class app {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("classpath:app-context-annotation.xml");
    ctx.refresh();

    ClientService clientService = ctx.getBean("jpaClientService", ClientService.class);
    UserService userService = ctx.getBean("jpaUserService", UserService.class);
    CustomerService customerService = ctx.getBean("jpaCustomerService", CustomerService.class);
    TroubleService troubleService = ctx.getBean("jpaTroubleService", TroubleService.class);

    clientList("Find all:", clientService.findAll());
    System.out.println(troubleService.findByClientId(5l));
}
private static void clientList (String message, List<Client> clientList) {
    System.out.println(message);
    for (Client client : clientList) {
        System.out.println(client);
    }
}}
```

Отрабатывает нормально (и другие методы тоже, в т.ч. DataJPA, ManyToOne, ManyToMany и др.)
Конфиг для него (**app-context-annotation.xml**) точно такой же, как ниже.

**webapp-context.xml**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd">
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysqlconnection.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${mysqlconnection.connection.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mysqlconnection.connection.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mysqlconnection.connection.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.chirkovds.springtest"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.GenerateDdl">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>-->
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>-->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.chirkovds.springtest"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="ru.chirkovds.springtest"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<annotation-driven/>
<resources location="/resources/"
           mapping="/resources/**" />
<default-servlet-handler/>
<beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jspx"/>
</beans:bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.chirkovds.springtest"/>
<interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
                p:paramName="Lang"/>
</interceptors>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
            id="messageSource"
            p:basenames="resources/i18n/messages, resources/i18n/application"
            p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
            id="localeResolver"
            p:cookieName="locale">
</beans:bean>
```

**index.jspx**

```
<?xml version="l.O" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
     xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
     xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
     version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_list" var="labelClientList"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_client" var="labelClient"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_inn" var="labelInn"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_specific" var="labelClientSpecific"/>
<h1>${labelClientList}</h1>
<c:if test="${not empty clients}">
    <tаblе>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>${labelClient}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${clients}" var="client">
            <tr>
                <td>${client.client}</td>
                <td>${client.inn}</td>
                <td>${client.client_specific}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </tаblе>
</c:if>
</div>
```

Уже второй день закончился - не могу найти, где нарукожопил...

UPD:
**ServerLog**

```
C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17\bin\catalina.bat run 
[2017-02-24 02:36:47,730] Artifact SpringTest:war exploded: Server is not
connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:
"C:\Users\Sky\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\index_jspx_SpringTest"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.516 INFO [main]
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:
Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.518 INFO [main]
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
Jan 10 2017 20:59:20 UTC
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.519 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.519 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.519 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.520 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.520 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.520 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Sky\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\index_jspx_SpringTest
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.520 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.520 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Sky\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\index_jspx_SpringTest\conf\logging.properties
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Sky\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\index_jspx_SpringTest
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17\temp
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;\e:\ZF\LeSSIS;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Users\Sky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Sky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.698 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.714 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.716 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.718 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 595 ms
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.798 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.799 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.843 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.850 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
24-Feb-2017 14:36:48.851 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 132 ms
[2017-02-24 02:36:49,175] Artifact SpringTest:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Connected to server
24-Feb-2017 14:36:51.293 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Feb-2017 14:36:51.344 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
24-Feb-2017 14:36:51.584 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Feb 24 14:36:51 GMT+07:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
24-Feb-2017 14:36:51.657 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webapp-context.xml]
24-Feb-2017 14:36:52.449 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webapp-context.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

24-Feb-2017 14:36:52.451 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-Feb-2017 14:36:52.452 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
24-Feb-2017 14:36:52.456 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Feb 24 14:36:51 GMT+07:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
24-Feb-2017 14:36:52.463 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Feb 24 14:36:51 GMT+07:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:581)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[2017-02-24 02:36:52,486] Artifact SpringTest:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Comment: Проверьте наличие в `WEB-INF/lib` файла spring-data-jpa-*.jar

Comment: А Maven сам не тянет зависимости?

Comment: Добавил. Вылезла другая. Пока пытаюсь сам разобрать. Спасибо большое

Comment: Спасибо. Докидал в lib jar-ников. Что-то стало воркать.
Прикольная приколюха, надо запомнить, что Maven, Tomcat и lib - это веселая штука :)